# RecyclerView IndexOutOfBounds Exceptions when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a RecyclerView which has some data.When it is scrolled to the bottom most position a Progressbar is displayed below and the some other items are inserted.But from the bottom most position when it is scrolled up multiple times I get **IndexOutOfBounds** Exception.Can anyone find where the problem lies?

Code:

RecyclerFrag.java:

```
public class Recycler_Frag extends Fragment {
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Intent intent;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    int previouslength;
    int counter = 1;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    boolean isScrolledup = false;
    private View view;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private int progressstatus;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_lyt, container, false);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (counter = 0; counter < 20; counter++) {
            arrayList.add(counter);
        }
        previouslength = arrayList.size();
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.rel);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                try {
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {

                        if (!isScrolledup) {

                            Log.e("U", "U");
                            isScrolledup = true;
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
//Layout which has the progressbar
                                    relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    while (counter < 30) {
                                        counter++;
                                        arrayList.add(counter);
                                        try {
                                            Thread.sleep(300);
                                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }

                                    relativeLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {

                                            recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(previouslength, arrayList.size() - previouslength);
                                            Log.e("S", "S");
                                            recyclerView.scrollToPosition(arrayList.size() - 1);
                                            Log.e("G", "G");
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            }).start();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "last", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerHolder> {

        @Override
        public RecyclerHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            return new RecyclerHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,
                    parent, false));
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.textView.setText(Integer.toString((Integer) arrayList.get(position)));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        public class RecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;

            public RecyclerHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.globemaster.samples, PID: 861
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{65444e5 position=30 id=-1, oldPos=20, pLpos:20 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{2c8745b VFED..... ......I. 0,0-720,1024 #7f08010a app:id/recycler}, adapter:com.globemaster.samples.Recycler_Frag$RecyclerAdapter@c2f74f8, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@5a88dd1, context:com.globemaster.samples.MainActivity@ef647f9
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5421)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5603)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3644)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3408)
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5817)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2759)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1528)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7530)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:622)
at android.view.Choreogra
```

Comment: @Dhruv..Could you help me with the problem I am facing

Comment: I removed the relativelayout that shows progressbar and it works fine.Can any one explain to me the reason?

Comment: Can you please check by changing id of a relative layout?

Comment: Tried it.That is not the problem

Comment: Yes, I also thought that it is not the problem.

Comment: Can you pls check the count of arraylist while you are calling `scrollToPosition` method?

Comment: 29.Total size is 30

Comment: @Dhruv what should be the parameters of notifyItemRangeInserted().Are the parameters i entered correct?

Comment: I solved it by adding the data to another arraylist and later loading the arraylist to first arraylist.